# Is there any way to have button in chat-bot created using Python, Flask, Chatterbot?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

I have tried to create chatbot using Python with Flask framework and Chatterbot module. Since We are training data from YAML file, GUI programming to get answers it bit confusing. I want to get button for some of Bot response when user clicks on particular button, bot should reply accordingly.

For Example -

Human - search some music.

Bot - What kind of Music you like.? 
     (Button 1 - Rock) (Button 2 - Classic) (Button 3- Pop)

(When user clicks on any of button, but should answer like that way. If user clicks on Pop)

Human - Pop

Bot - great, searching Pop music for you.!

Is there any way to structure YAML file for button.? Or any other way.?

Comment: Does the unconventional use, at least for English, of a period before the exclamation and question mark have any special meaning?

Comment: No, It is just chatbot response from trained data which I trained in .yml file.